# Click function not executing executing Nightmare.js

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to do some scraping with `nightmare` and my work is almost functional. The problem is that I'm facing an issue when I try to perform a `click()` after the `evaluate()` and `run()` have been called. After I run those two functions I'm trying to perform another click to move myself to another part of the website, but is not executing the `click()`.

At this point I'm note sure whats the issue, I have few assumptions, maybe those functions are asynchronous and I'm trying to `click()` when the callbacks arent ready yet or one of those functions ends de current `nightmare` object and I dont have the scope anymore.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
//var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true})
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

var urlWeb = "someurl";
var selectCity = "#ddl_city";
var selectTheater = "#ddl_theater";
var enterBtn = "#btn_enter";
var mainSelector = "#aspnetForm";
var flagReady = true;

new Nightmare({show:true})
.goto(urlWeb)
.wait(selectCity)
.select(selectCity, '19')
.wait(8000)
.select(selectTheater, '12')
.wait(1000)
.click(enterBtn)
.wait(mainSelector)
.evaluate(function(){

        //returning HTML for cheerio
        return document.body.innerHTML; 
})
.run(function(err, nightmare){
     if (err) return console.log(err);

    // Loading HTML body on jquery cheerio
     var $ = cheerio.load(nightmare);

    //Looping on each div for seccion de Carterla para Hoy
    $('.showtimeDaily').each(function(index, element){
        //spanish title
        console.log($(this).find('h3').children().text());
        //english title
        console.log($(this).find('h4').text());
        //schedule for today
        console.log($(this).find('li').children().text() + " ");
        //img for movie
        console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            //show time data such as gender, lenght, language
        console.log($(this).find('.showtimeData').text());
        var showtimeData = $(this).find('.showtimeData').text();
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(showtimeData.replace(/\t|\n/g, "")));
    })

        console.log('Done!');


})
//*****here is wen I try to click*****
.click('a[href="../showtimes/weekly.aspx"]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issue with the asynchronous call backs, so what I did is that I nested calls of the nightmare object to make sure that the tasks were running one after the other one. This is the code:

```
nightmare
.goto(urlWeb)
.wait(selectCity)
.select(selectCity, '19')
.wait(8000)
.select(selectTheater, '12')
.wait(1000)
.click(enterBtn)
.wait(mainSelector)
.evaluate(function(){

        //returning HTML for cheerio
        return document.body.innerHTML; 
})
.then(function(body){
    // Loading HTML body on jquery cheerio
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    //Looping on each div for seccion de Carterla para Hoy
    $('.showtimeDaily').each(function(index, element){
        //spanish title
        console.log($(this).find('h3').children().text());
        //english title
        console.log($(this).find('h4').text());
        //schedule for today
        console.log($(this).find('li').children().text() + " ");
        //img for movie
        console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            //show time data such as gender, lenght, language
        console.log($(this).find('.showtimeData').text());
        var showtimeData = $(this).find('.showtimeData').text();
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(showtimeData.replace(/\t|\n/g, "")));
    })
   //**Here I call nightmare to run after the first call back is done*****
    nightmare
        .goto('')
        .wait('body')
        .title()
        .then(function(title){
            console.log(title);
        });

        console.log('Done!');


});
```